# Adesigns Bundle Fullcalendar extends class

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar, overriding, bundle

how can i do the extend because i have done this :

```
namespace Calendar\CalendarBundle\Entity;

use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Seance
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="seance")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Calendar\CalendarBundle\Repository\SeanceRepository")
 */
class Seance extends EventEntity {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected  $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="seance_type", type="string", length=8)
 */
private $seanceType;
}
```

and when i do

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

i have just the attributes of the class Seance

CREATE TABLE seance (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, seance_type VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the Entity in the bundle ADesigns there is no @ORM\Column before the attribut